# Deployment job in jenkins from s3 bucket to aws codedeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

Trying to create a simple deployment job on jenkins with the plugin post-build aws codedeploy.
The issue i'm facing is not able to target an s3 zip file as a deployment target. I don't want to upload nothing from codedeploy, just simply trigger a deployment from jenkins with a proper configuration ( bucket, region and of course the package.zip, which is already exists in the bucket )
Is there any "easy" way i can do that?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/setting-up-the-jenkins-plugin-for-aws-codedeploy/
Current setup works as charmed, the deployment is triggered on aws but with wrong target file so the deployment fails at the moment. There is no chance to merge the build(and upload to s3) and deploy job together.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to aws-cli for properly target a bucket for deployment. There is no way to use the plugin for situation like this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having build and deploy as two different stages you can have both in same stage where the jenkins job will checkout from the pipeline and codedeploy post job will automatically zip and store the revision in S3 actually this is the way I achieved it. But the best way is to use AWS cli.